# Is this paradigm called "linked functions" or is there another specific term for such a paradigm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

One function contains another function and this additional function is called in the original function.
the code:

```
def funktion0(arg0):
    arg0+=1
    def funktion1(arg1):
        arg1+=1
        return arg1
    return funktion1(arg0)

print(funktion0(1))
```

expected output: 3
actual output: 3

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The example shows "nested functions".

Comment: expected output: 3 actual output: 3?? Then whats the problem?

Comment: Using `+=` doesn't really accomplish anything here if you intended to pass immutable values to each function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called nested functions, but it isn't really a paradigm.